# Creating a boxplot for each column in R

Tags: r, dataframe, data-science, boxplot

I have a dataframe like:

```
       X1    X2   X3 ...

Title  One  Two   Three

X1    0     10     19
X2    4     20      3
X3   17     39      3
..
```

I would like to create a Boxplots with the title of it being 'Title' (one, two or three) and the corresponding data in each column being used. So, I want a Boxplot for each column. How can I do this?

The Y-axis is X1, X2... (in the leftmost column)
 (which should just be 1, 2..) and the x-axis is the Title.

[image: My data frame]

[image: Data frame with columns headers]

Comment: The fact that your first row is full of characters and the rest of your data are numbers is going to cause you a massive headache. Fix this first.  The easiest way is probably to apply the fix during the import (e.g. `read.csv(file="myfile.csv", header=TRUE)`.

Comment: This is actually what I've produced from unstructured data. Is there not a way I could make a box plot from the numeric data and attach the title somehow?

Comment: Remove the titles from your dataframe, store them in a separate vector (let's call it `namevec`), and then make your boxplot like this:  `boxplot(df, names=namevec)`.

Comment: Sorry, I will try that, but I have just made the column headers the titles. Does this make it easier? Picture above

Comment: Check that your data are numeric with `str(df)`.  If so, then just do `boxplot(df)`.

Comment: It says its a factor with 6 levels, but then when I try to convert to numeric the numbers completely change?

Comment: `df$x <- as.numeric(as.character(df$x))`

Comment: Okay, this works except for the fact that the numbers represent the frequency of X1, X2, X3, X4, and X5. How can I represent it so these X1-X5 are on the Y-axis and the frequencies fill the Boxplots?

Answer (score 4):

```
library(reshape2)
library(ggplot2)

x <- data.frame('One' = c(0, 4, 17), 'Two' = c(10, 20, 39), 'Three' = c(19, 3, 3))
x <- melt(x)

plt <- ggplot(data = x, aes(x = variable, y = value))
plt + geom_boxplot() + theme_minimal() + labs(x = "Title", y = "x")
```

[image]

Comment: I can't seem to get this working, what should I replace 'variable' and 'value' with? I have posted my exact data frame which I simplified

Comment: `variable` and `value` are actually correct; they are just the default names provided by `melt()` when you reshape your data

Answer (score 2):

In base R:

```
df <- data.frame(
     'One'   = c( 0,  4, 17), 
     'Two'   = c(10, 20, 39),
     'Three' = c(19,  3,  3))

boxplot(df, main="My Title")
```

Comment: I get the error Error in oldClass(stats) <- cl : 
  adding class "factor" to an invalid object - I have posted a screenshot of my exact data frame which I simplified

Answer (score 0):

```
df <- data.frame(
 'One'   = c( 0,  4, 17), 
 'Two'   = c(10, 20, 39),
 'Three' = c(19,  3,  3))

lapply(seq_along(df), function(x){
 boxplot(df[[x]], main = paste("Title", colnames(df))[[x]])
})
```

Comment: While this might answer the authors' question, it lacks some explaining words and/or links to documentation. Raw code snippets are not very helpful without some phrases around them. You may also find [how to write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) very helpful. Please edit your answer.